# Orchard CMS Adding a links in HTML widget

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to add links to pages in the HTML widget.

I'm currently running orchard as a virtual directory, so I can't use `'/'`.  Also since I'm working on a dev site then copying over to a live site, I'm not sure if the site will be running as a virtual directory or from the root.

I've just realised that all links entered via the HTML widget will have a problem, since you can't use `'~'`, also it looks like the image links are fixed, so deploying to a different location won't work ie. from localhost\dev to localhost\live

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're entering it from the html editor, you don't have any choice but to use a rooted path (/foo). Sure, it can cause problems if you then publish from a vdir into a site without a vdir, but that's how it for now. We're looking at solutions but in the meantime your best bet is to have a dev site that is as close as possible to the production setup.

Comment: having spent more time with it, I came to the same conclusion.

Comment: perhaps some post processing in the display of the body part could do it?

Comment: perhaps some post processing in the driver of the body part could do the trick? some url prefix detection after the model update to extract application relative urls and store them using the ~ syntax. Then the inverse during display. Im am aware it could ultimately lead to robustness issues, but nothing I see yet. (But again, I didn't think about it a lot). I could try an implementation myself, and submit it.

Comment: Precisely the solution we're considering, yes.

Comment: Marvelous! Have you thought about exposing this pre/post processing as an extension point for the body module? I could very well use it to perform a lot of things with text rendering, especially using HTML5 app specific attributes. (forum RPG games requires text scrambling for instance)

Comment: Exactly, yes. I'd like us to ship a simple filter relying on tokens, but one could build others to do some Razor processing, profanity filtering, or who knows what.

Comment: Anyone know if there has been any progress on this?

Answer (score 2):

As [pointed out by randompete on codeplex](http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/279418), another solution could be implementing your own IHtmlFilter. I wrote a simple implementation which you can find here: http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/279418 
It basically post-processes the BodyPart text by replacing all occurences of urls starting with ~/ with a resolved url (using the UrlHelper.Content() method)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to display a link pointing to a static resource, you can use:

```
@Html.Link(string textlink, string url)
```

But Html.Link doesn't supports application relatives urls (~/[...] ones)

if you need only the href (as for an img ). It supports ~/ urls.

```
src='@Href(string url)'
```

If you need to display a link to an action

```
 @Html.ActionLink(...) <-- lots of overloads.
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however I was specifically referring to using the HTML widget, which won't allow server side code.

Comment: ah ok, I read "widget" and didn't understand you were speaking of this specific widget with an html editor.